# Configuring Hive with Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I need to execute queries on HBase using hive. I have downloaded the HBase and hive my HMaster is running fine; I need to know what configuration changes I need to do for hive to work with HBase as the back end database. Any link tutorial will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apache Hive wiki explains it nicely https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

To create an HBase table that is managed from hive try something like

```
CREATE TABLE hive_managed(key string, value1 string, value2 int)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,columnFamilyName:val1,columnFamilyName:val2")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hivemanaged");
```

*edited following comment

Comment: What exactly should be the host file contents, because seperatly i can create table through hive and hbase but using hive i am not able to create table in hbase. 

i need to build a pseudo distributed hbase/hive/hadoop setup.

Comment: Thanx for reply, first of all i am not able to make hbase hive and hadoop as pseudo distributive, what setting should be there in these configuration files and the host file and the hostname file i am using ubuntu distribution

Comment: Cloudera has a good installation guide @ https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation+Guide