# Continuous data migration from mysql to Hbase

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, data-migration

I have installed hadoop and hbase for real time analytics purpose. The proble I face is to migrate data on line from mysql to Hbase.

The sqoop tool is useful to do bulk data migrations, is there any way that the data from mysql can be transfered to HBase on line (then and there when an insert/update/delete happens). So that real time analytics can be achieved. Not near-real-time.

Please help me on this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you faced task of setting up replication between different DBMS. It is a case when native replication mechanism is not useful.
Simplest solution would be create set of triggers over tables you want to replicate - and write the data to be replicated into some additional table. Then you can set up monitoring this table and apply changes to the HBase. 
More robust, but more complicated solution would be to analyze MySQL log used for its native replication mechanism and apply the changes to the HBase. 
In the same time it is not clear for me hoe HBase will give you real-time analytics. I wrote abit about this issue here:
[Group by In HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126489/group-by-in-hbase)

Comment: Thanks David for sharing you thoughts. Actually my task was to come up haddop and hbase for analytics. As you mentioned above it is a good idea to use MySQL log. My plad was to 
1. migrate data from MySQL to HBase.
2. I have come up with a data model in HBase for every analytic reports.
3. I assume using MR jobs I can populate this reports table using the above migrated data.

I am not pretty sure where to use HIVE or I'm on right track. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: I would consider to migreate data right into hive and do all your aggregation / reporting using HQL (SQL like language). Then results of the reporting (especially if they are of modest size) can be migrated back to MySQL. You will not achive real time up to seconds and even probably up to minute. BUt it will be simple and very scalable solution. <br> I still not sure how HBase came here into the picture. <br>

Comment: Thanks David. HBase comes into picture because we anticipate large data in near future. There will be thousands of restaurants will be integrated so that the amount of transaction data will be large. Based on the transaction data analytic reports will be generated. 

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Please estimate number of requests per second you expect

Answer (score 2):

To add more information about where to use Hive in your project, there are multiple setups that you can integrate Hive and HBase to work together.  For instance, if you use AWS, you can install HBase/Hive on the same hadoop cluster to run join queries on Hive table and Hbase table together.  Or you can separate HBase and Hive into two different clusters and reference HBase data from your Hive queries.  If you use Cloudera distribution, you can do the same thing too.

Reference:

- http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/apache-hbase-on-emr.html
- http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/06/integrating-hive-and-hbase