# Replicating data from mySQL to Hbase using flume: how?

Tags: mysql, hbase, database-replication, flume

I have a large mySQL database with heavy load and would like to replicate the data in this database to Hbase in order to do analytical work on it.

***edit***: I want the data to replicate relatively quickly,  and without any schema changes (no timestamped rows, etc)

I've read that this can be done using flume,  with mySQL as a source,  possibly the mySQL bin logs,  and Hbase as a sink,  but haven't found any detail (high or low level).    What are the major tasks to make this work?

Similar question were asked and answered earlier but didn't really explain how or point to resources that would:

[Flume to migrate data from MySQL to Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548538/flume-to-migrate-data-from-mysql-to-hadoop)

[Continuous data migration from mysql to Hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919638/continuous-data-migration-from-mysql-to-hbase)

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using [SQOOP](http://sqoop.apache.org/) for this purpose, IMHO. It was developed for exactly this purpose. Flume was made for a rather different purpose, like aggregating log data, data generated from sensors etc.

See [this](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_mysql) for more details.

Comment: is sqoop effective for immediate replication?    looks like its for batch-type replication

Comment: Correct. But, how immediate is your immediate? If it about incremental load, scoop can handle that.

Comment: every 5 minutes would be sufficient.   does sqoop require schema changes,  e.g. each table has to have an increasing primary key or date-type column?     (this wouldn't be the end of the world if so -- but if flume can just run without mods that would give it the nod)

Answer (score 1):

So far there are three options worth considering:

1. Sqoop: After initial bulk import, it supports two types of incremental udpates import: APPEND, LAST-MODFIED. But being said, It won't give you Real-Time or even near Real-Time replication. It's not because Sqoop can't run that fast, it's because you don't want to plug in a Sqoop pipe to your Mysql server and puling data every 1 or 2 mins.
2. Trigger: This is a quick-dirty solution, by adding triggers to the source RDBMS, and update your HBase according. This one gives you Real-Time satisfaction. But you have to mess up the source DB by adding triggers. It might be ok as a temporal solution, but long term, it just won't do.
3. Flume: This one, you will need to put in the most development effort. It doesn't need to touch the DB, it doesn't add in Reading traffic to the DB neither(It tails the transaction logs).

Personally I'd go for flume, not only it channels the data from RDBMS to your HBase, but also can you do something with the data while they are streaming through your flume pipe. (e.g. transformation, notification, alerting etc etc)